# word breaking under the following sibling

Tags: css

I want to create something like this:

[image]

And this is what I tried:

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: #E6E9F0;
  border: solid 1px black;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
}

.left,
.right {
  display: inline-block;
}

.right {
  white-space: break-spaces;
  margin: 0;
  word-break: break-word;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 6px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="left">Text</span>
  <span class="right">Very very veeeeeeeeeeeeeery veeeeeery very very very long text</span>
</div>
```

I couldn't figure out how to do it without inserting the first span in the second one, in my example I want both spans to be in the same hierarchy.

How can I solve this?

Comment: remove the `display: inline-block;` from both `<span>`'s and let them default to `inline`. You also do not need that `float: left;`

Comment: @Johannes why float the span, when it just needs to be inline, which is its default behavior?

Comment: @zgood yes, you are right - I am thinking around too many corners today...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you have white space nowrap on the container if you just want it to wrap normally? Remove that and all styles after your container apart from your red:

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #E6E9F0;
  border: solid 1px black;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
}

.left {
  margin-right: 6px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="left">Text</span>
  <span class="right">Very very veeeeeeeeeeeeeery veeeeeery very very very long text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: `vertical-align`, `display`, and `margin-right` can also be removed.

Comment: @Sean depends what that element is next to and if it needs aligning to the top of it and OP may want the extra space on the right of the red text